# order of elements in direct product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have a conceptual question: if a group has 1 element of order 1 and 1 element of order 2 (e.g., nonzero reals), what changes if your take its direct/cartesian product as a group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g \in G$ has order $m$, and $h \in H$ has order $n$, then $(g, h) \in G \times H$ has order $lcm(m, n)$.

For example, consider the element $(1, 2) \in \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_6$.